# How to convert XML into PDF/A using java api?

Tags: xml, pdfa

I am trying with JAX-B and iText to convert the XML into PDF,
Can anyone suggest me which API is best suitable for this requirement.

Comment: please share what you have tried, then then come back with your source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache FOP API and you need to write XSLT style for your output PDF. This API will help to convert your XML and XSLT stylesheet into PDF/PDF-A.